# Eclipse PTP: Running parallel (MPI) applications on the local machine?

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

How must eclipse PTP be configured to run MPI applications using OpenMPI on the local machine? Using "Add Resource Manager", I can choose OpenMPI and switch on to Localhost in "Connection name". But still, I'm asked for some user and password name. Is this the right way?

Comment: Have you checked the PTP documentation on [Configuring Resource Managers](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2F02resMgrSetup.html)? It has an example that specifically covers Open MPI.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to reproduce the example, I don't have the option "Remote service provider" in the "Open MPI connection configuration". I can just provide the "Connection name".

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 (the highest version I have preinstalled) with PTP 5.0.7 works exactly as shown in the example. I have successfully compiled a Hello World MPI project and run it with local Open MPI launcher.

Comment: I have installed PTP 6.0, and it seems that using the "Resource manager" is obsolete and one has to do it in another way, but I end up in the same problem to specify a localhost connection: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftoc.html

Comment: Found the problem and it was not related to eclipse/PTP: I had to install an ssh server on my system. PTP's error message was not very useful to find the problem and its not clear why it must connect to the local system via ssh. But does not matter, now it works. @HristoIliev: Thanks for your help, PTP seems to be the right one for my purposes.

Comment: I've just installed Eclipse Juno. It seems like (also confirmed by the documentation of PTP 6.0) that even for local machines it makes an SSH connection. I don't know why when `orterun` can happily run as many processes as one wants on the localhost... Well, I'm glad it works for you - happy MPI debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Then follow this instructions on the PTP documentation.