# Eclipse PTP OpenMPI parallel run/debug

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, parallel-processing, fortran

Can someone give instructions on how to run/debug an OpenMPI (C/C++/Fortran) program in Eclipse PTP using the actual parallel run/debug modes on a local machine?

I've set a local connection in the 'Remote Environments' section. If I specify the actual program executable as the executable then eclipse gets stuck with 'submit interactive' and 'Launching... Submitting the job...' in the progress window, and I'm left with the specified number of processes of the program running at full CPU indefinitely. If I specify another program, like mpirun or mpiexec, and provide the necessary arguments to get to the program executable then the only difference is that I have the same number of mpirun's running at 0 CPU.

I should add that if I actually select "Local" under "Connection Type" then I get an error:

> Failed to execute command: ompi_info -a --parseable
>
> Reason: Cannot run program "ompi_info": Unknown reason

even though that command works fine from the command line and runs successfully when connecting to local host as setup in the 'remote environments'

I've seen the guides on the Eclipse website, but they're no help. I've checked [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051266/eclipse-ptp-running-parallel-mpi-applications-on-the-local-machine) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program/10832917#10832917), but I still get this working right.

I can get a program running successfully in parallel by treating it like a normal program and setting the executable to mpiexec and providing the necessary arguments, but I want to do actual parallel debugging, so this doesn't suffice.

EDIT:
I should be more specific. I know there are other methods of debugging, but Eclipse PTP (parallel tools platform) should be able to handle this perfectly, so I'm looking for an explanation from someone who has setup Eclipse PTP on their local machine such that they can use a parallel run configuration and the parallel debugging tools.

Answer (score 2):

Please ask your question on the ptp-user mailing list.
https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/ptp-user
Sounds like openmpi isn't in the path available within eclipse

In fact, this is in the PTP FAQ on [https://wiki.eclipse.org/Parallel_Tools_Platform_FAQ#Q:_I_get_the_error_.22Failed_to_execute_command:_ompi_info_-a_--parseable.22_when_I_use_the_Open_MPI_target_configuration_on_my_Mac](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Parallel_Tools_Platform_FAQ#Q%3a_I_get_the_error_.22Failed_to_execute_command%3a_ompi_info_-a_--parseable.22_when_I_use_the_Open_MPI_target_configuration_on_my_Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually used the Eclipse IDE, but I debug my MPI code using `xterm` and `gdb`:

```
mpirun -np 2 xterm -e gdb -ex run ./tool
```

Not exactly what you where after, but perhaps it helps...

Comment: Thanks. I'm going after instructions for using this specific tool, but I may end up falling back on another method like this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OS you're using, but I had this issue on MacOS. It's because Eclipse doesn't run .bash_profile or .bashrc, so its environment (namely `PATH`) won't have everything it needs. You could try to edit the `PATH` variable to include it by [some other means](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Parallel_Tools_Platform_FAQ#Q%3A_I_get_the_error_.22Failed_to_execute_command%3A_ompi_info_-a_--parseable.22_when_I_use_the_Open_MPI_target_configuration_on_my_Mac) (which I found to be overly complicated on Mac), OR you can just run the `eclipse` executable from a shell so that it inherits your typical environment. For me this was located at:

`~/eclipse/parallel-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`

Then eclipse was able to detect OpenMPI just fine (`PATH` contained `/usr/local/bin`).